# prevent explicit invocation of an overridable method (Java)

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

I have a number of classes that define a method, and I want to execute some code (say, some "prologue" and "epilogue") around that method:

```
public interface Thing {
    public void stuff();
    public void callStuff();
}
public abstract class Something implements Thing {
    public abstract void stuff();
    public void callStuff() {
        ... // common prologue
        //try {
            stuff();
        //} finally {
            ... // common epilogue
        //}
    }
}
public class A extends Something {
    public void stuff() { ... }
}
public class B extends Something {
    public void stuff() { ... }
}
public class Wrapper extends Thing {
    private Thing t;
    Wrapper(Thing thing) { t = thing; }
    public void stuff() { t.stuff(); }
    public void callStuff() { t.callStuff(); }
}

// Use:
Something s = ...;
s.callStuff();
```

You see that the idea is that subclasses will redefine *`stuff()`* while the clients will invoke *`callStuff()`*. Nevertheless, in some rare cases one has to call *`stuff()`*, see `Wrapper` above.

Something like that we see in the `Thread` class (since JDK 1.0), child classes redefine *`run()`* but the clients invoke *`start()`*.

***How do I prevent clients from calling `stuff()` directly?***

EDIT

`protected` does not work here because the "clients" really are children of `Something` coded by another team. `@Deprecated` would work, but *`stuff()`* is not really deprecated, and everyone knows what "deprecated" is, so I cannot redefine the meaning of `@Deprecated`.

Ideally, the compilation should fail unless an explicit directive is given to ignore the problem.

Comment: Make it `protected` ?

Comment: `protected` will not help: it is child classes that must not invoke _stuff()_ directly.